Can we trust our ears in speech recognition in an audio file?
Can we trust our ears in speech recognition in an audio file?

I’m voting to close this question because this is a software configuration question, not a physics question.

If you start with an empty project in Logic Pro then nothing can "appear" in the project unless you add it or create it. Everything that is in your project will appear in the track or clip list (even if you have made that track inaudible). If you have deleted the files you are concerned about then you cannot even unintentionally add them to your Logic Pro project. So, no, your old files cannot possibly appear in your music audio.
